# What do I have to do with the variable count in order to pass this tutorial about JavaScript function scopes?

Tags: javascript

The [tutorial](http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/lesson?id=1055&lang=en) says:

> Define a function named callFunc that takes one argument, a function
>   f. It should return an array containing the values f(0), f(0), f(1),
>   f(1). You can only call f twice.

This is what the tutorial gives:

```
var count = 0;
var f = function (x) {
    count += 1;
    return x + 2;
};


var callFunc = function (f) {

};
```

I have no idea how to use `count` to pass this tutorial.
Any suggestions?

Comment: where did you get the idea that you'd need a variable count? the tutorial doesn't seem to say anything about that and it seems to make little sense.

Comment: @Patrick Huy It is included in the tutorial (in the 'show prelude').

Comment: WOW that tutorial is off the rails ..... im sure there are easier tutorials on JavaScript around the internet ....

Comment: The word **count** doesnt appear on the page you linked - i just searched it !!!!

Comment: alexchenco: ahh! I see! It was hidden. You are probably supposed to pass the var f into the function callFunc(), the implementation of callFunc is rather trivial and does not require usage of the variable count.

Comment: I love how the tutorial concludes that functions are values just because you can assign them to a variable

Comment: I am following a bad tutorial?

Comment: Well considering that functions in javascript are first class objects and the author saying `functions are values, just like the number 5` is so far off the base that I wouldn't trust it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `count`. Just call `f()` twice and put the return values into an array:

```
var callFunc = function (f) {
  var f0 = f(0);
  var f1 = f(1);
  return [f0, f0, f1, f1];
};
```

Comment: `var f0 = f(0), f1 = f(1);` and it will pass the tutorial! :D

Comment: @Adam Zalcman if you click submit you get: ERROR  Problem at line 3 character 7: Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.
FAILED JSLint errors

Comment: @alexchenco Well, it's a style suggestion to use a single `var` statement to declare both `f0` and `f1`. If you try to follow their suggestion the error will disappear.

Comment: Strange I passed the tutorial with this: `var callFunc = function (f) {
  var f0, f1;
  f0 = f(0);
  f1 = f(1);
  return [f0, f0, f1, f1];
};`

Comment: @alexchenco Thanks for posting the question. I've also been trying versions of Adam's answer for 30 minutes!!!